# Is it possible to pipe the results of FIND to a COPY command CP?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, find, xargs

Is it possible to pipe the results of `find` to a COPY command `cp`?

Like this:

```
find . -iname "*.SomeExt" | cp Destination Directory
```

Seeking, I always find this kind of formula [such as from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18339127/4070433):

```
find . -name "*.pdf" -type f -exec cp {} ./pdfsfolder \;
```

This raises some questions:

1. Why cant you just use `|` pipe? isn't that what its for?
2. Why does everyone recommend the `-exec`
3. How do I know when to use that (exec) over pipe `|`?

Comment: `cp` does not accept stdin afaik.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash: find and copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562102/bash-find-and-copy).

Comment: Assuming your `find` has `-exec ... +` and you protect your filename across pipe/xargs, it really shouldn't matter which you use. If your `find` does not have `-exec ... +`, then a careful pipe/xargs should always be preferred with any command that can take multiple filename arguments.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Good question!

> 1. why cant you just use | pipe? isn't that what its for?

You can pipe, of course, `xargs` is done for these cases:

```
find . -iname "*.SomeExt" | xargs cp Destination_Directory/
```

> 2. Why does everyone recommend the -exec

The `-exec` is good because it provides more control of exactly what you are executing. Whenever you pipe there may be problems with corner cases: file names containing spaces or new lines, etc.

> 3. how do I know when to use that (exec) over pipe | ?

It is really up to you and there can be many cases. I would use `-exec` whenever the action to perform is simple. I am not a very good friend of `xargs`, I tend to prefer an approach in which the `find` output is provided to a `while` loop, such as:

```
while IFS= read -r result
do
    # do things with "$result"
done < <(find ...)
```

Comment: This did not work for me, needed to add the -t flag to cp command to work

Answer (score 38):

There's a little-used option for `cp`: `-t destination` -- see the man page:

```
find . -iname "*.SomeExt" | xargs cp -t Directory
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use `|` like below:

```
find . -iname "*.SomeExt" | while read line
do
  cp $line DestDir/
done
```

Answering your questions:

- `|` can be used to solve this issue. But as seen above, it involves a lot of code. Moreover, `|` will create two process - one for `find` and another for `cp`.
- Instead using `exec()` inside `find` will solve the problem in a single process.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```sh
find . -iname "*.SomeExt" -print0  | xargs -0 cp -t Directory
# ........................^^^^^^^..........^^
```

In case there is whitespace in filenames.

Answer (score 2):

I like the spirit of the response from @fedorqui-so-stop-harming, but it needed a tweak to work in my bash terminal.

In this version...

```
find . -iname "*.SomeExt" | xargs cp Destination_Directory/
```

The `cp` command incorrectly takes `Destination_Directory/` as the first argument. I needed to add a replacement string in order to get `xargs` to insert the argument in the right position for `cp`. I used a percent symbol for the replacement string, but you can use anything that doesn't conflict with the input from the pipe. This version works for me.

```
find . -iname "*.SomeExt" | xargs -I % cp % Destination_Directory/
```

Answer (score 1):

This SOLVED my problem.

```
find . -type f | grep '\.pdf' |  while read line 
do
        cp $line REPLACE_WITH_TARGET_DIRECTORY
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are spaces in the filenames, try:

```
find . -iname *.ext > list.txt
cat list.txt | awk 'BEGIN {a="'"'"'"}{print "cp "a$0a" Directory"}' > script.sh
sh script.sh
```

You can inspect `list.txt` and `script.sh` before `sh script.sh`. Remember to delete the `list.txt` and `script.sh` afterwards.

I had some files with parenthesis and wanted a progress bar, so replaced the `cat` line with:

`cat list.txt | awk -v X='"' '{print "rsync -Pa "X$0X" /Volumes/Untitled/"}' > script.sh`